Why does an error occur when determining if a number is within a certain range?
The expression "1/Sqrt[6]" is within the range of "1/Sqrt[7] <= rate <= 1/2," so why does the result of the operation produce an error?)?
MemberQ[FunctionRange[{1/Sqrt[7 - 2 Sqrt[3] t + t^2], 
   0 <= t <= Sqrt[3]}, t, rate], 1/Sqrt[6]]


MemberQ expects a list as first argument, not an inequality!
Try
FunctionRange[{1/Sqrt[7 - 2 Sqrt[3] t + t^2], 0 <= t <= Sqrt[3]}, t,rate] /. rate -> 1/Sqrt[6]
(* True *)

